# explode values from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I have mysql table with 3 column   id  |  name  |  numbers .In numbers column I have numbers example : 1,4,5 now I echo values from rows :

```
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$numbers = $row['numbers'];
echo "$id | $name | $numbers ";
```

This code display me this : 1 | Name | 1,4,5

I want to explode field numbers and display like this : 1 | Name | 1 4 5.So these number I want to be separatly displayed.Thank you

Comment: A side note: having something in a comma separated way in database is likely to be a very bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$numbers = $row['numbers'];
echo "$id | $name | ";
foreach (explode(',', $numbers) as $n) {
    echo "{$n} ";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
$numbers = str_replace(',',' ',$row['numbers']);
```

Comment: Guy, he said `I want to explode field numbers`

Comment: @BogdanBurim i know he want explode but his expected output can be achieve through easier way. then why explode and the loop through it.

Comment: Well I don't think that his main aim is to output this values (in such  way), I think he will use them somehow other way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explode `$numbers` with `,` as the delimiter and then print it using foreach

```
foreach (explode(',', $numbers) as $num) {
echo $num;
}
```

Add the above code after printing ID and Name

Answer (score 0):

you need to use explode function

```
$date="23-02-2014";

$date1=explode("-"$date);

$fdate=("$date1[2]"."-"."$date1[1]"."-"."$date[0]");

echo  $fdate;

result is 2014-02-23
```

Answer (score -1):

The list() is used to assign a list of variables in one operation, and its a good way of assign array items to variables.

Example ;

```
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$numbers = array( $row['numbers']);

list($fnum, $snum, $tnum) = $numbers;

echo $fnum . $snum . $tnum ;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: It certainly does.  exploding array of numbers? Would be glad to see what does it better

Comment: The existing answers do.